# How to hide the different dropdown with the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried this code below. I expected that the dropdown menu could hide when I clicked other elements. However, I duplicated a same li with the same class name. I clicked the first "Product" dropdown, then I clicked the other "Product", but the first dropdown menu didn't hide.

Could anyone help me out with this? I am a JavaScript beginner. Thank you so much!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Show hide popover
        $(".dropdown").click(function() {
            $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(event) {
        var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
        if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
            $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `$trigger !== event.target` always passes, as `$trigger` is a jQuery object and `event.target` refers to a DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `click` event, you can close all dropdowns with `$(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");`, and then open just the selected one with `$(this).children(".dropdown-menu").slideDown("fast");`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).children(".dropdown-menu").is(":visible")) {
      $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").slideDown("fast");
    } else {
      $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

meabe:

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  // when click to the element dropdown required close all dropdowns first
  $(".dropdown").each((element,i)=>{
    $(element).find(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
  });
  //then open this
  $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
});
```